# UILocalNotification fireDate Q

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, notifications

I've made a  LocalNotification app and all is working fine, after setting up the fireDate for dateComponents, however,  when i pub the, tableview like this :

```
NSArray *reminderArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *notif = [reminderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


[cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description ]];
```

the detailtextlabel   is 1 hour earlier the the time picked, i cant  find the problem, the reminder fires at the right time.

hope u can help me out ....

Thanks Skov

Comment: What is your timezone? Also, can you post the output of `[notif.fireDate description]`?

Comment: NSDate *pickerDate = [NSDate date];
    [self.datePicker setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [self.datePicker setDate:pickerDate];

Comment: and thh notif.fireDate description  gives me  2011-01-16 22:18 but the picked time is 23:18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `[notif.fireDate description]` to display a date in the UI. Apple may change the format how `NSDate` describes itself at any time. Currently, it displays itself in GMT but not even that is certain.

Use an `NSDateFormatter` to display a date on screen.